# Checking if values in a specific column are the same in the same column for the line below?

Tags: linux, bash, text-manipulation

I am looking for a Linux command in which I can compare if, for a single column, the line below is the same value as the line currently being checked, and if they are then output both lines. My file is tab separated.

Input example:

```
line 1  1   var281  7

line 2  1   var100  80

line 3  1   var99   85

line 4  2   var281  90

line 5  2   var281  91

line 6  2   var300  61

line 7  3   var50   45

line 8  3   var99   14

line 9  3   var99   19

line 10 3   var670  80
```

Desired Output:

```
line 4  2   var281  90

line 5  2   var281  91

line 8  3   var99   14

line 9  3   var99   19
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
sed '/^\s*$/d;s/\s[0-9][^ ]*$//g' inputfile | uniq -D -f3
```

Here sed deletes empty lines (`^\s*$`) as well as the last field of inputfile.  Uniq prints duplicate lines ignoring the first three fields (`-f3`). The output is:

```
line 4 2 var281
line 5 2 var281
line 8 3 var99
line 9 3 var99
```

Note last field is not printed. To have it printed you could use grep:

```
grep "$(sed '/^\s*$/d;s/\s[0-9][^ ]*$//g' inputfile | uniq -D -f3)" inputfile
```

output:

```
line 4 2 var281 90
line 5 2 var281 91
line 8 3 var99 14
line 9 3 var99 19
```

Comment: can you please explain the part: `s/\s[0-9][^ ]*$` in your given post.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: That will match space `\s` followed by a digit `[0-9]` followed by zero or more non-spaces `[^ ]*` followed by the end of the line `$`